# How to avoid red cross (no image) when loading jQuery Thickbox?

Tags: jquery, thickbox

When loading a jQuery Thickbox, a red cross is displayed while the content is loaded.

How to avoid that? Or, Is it possible to change that red cross for something else?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using asp.net.

Comment: From the Thickbox homepage: While Thickbox had its day, it is not maintained any longer, so we recommend you use some alternatives. * colorbox * jQueryUI Dialog * fancybox * DOM window * shadowbox.js -The Management. 9.30.2009 (and Paul Irish) –

Comment: ASP.NET is totally not relevant here, removed the tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought the solution could have been related to the way I was calling the thickbox from asp.net. That's the reason why the tag was there. Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @redsquare thanks a lot for the info. Which one would you recommend me to use? Basically, I am using it to load content in GridViews (not too much though) and to display small forms. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would look at http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ or jquery ui if your already using the ui

Comment: The problem is missing image - per @redsquare answer, adding it in the correct place should solve the current problem you experience..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is hardcoded into the js

```
var tb_pathToImage = "images/loadingAnimation.gif";
```

Do you have this in your solution?